# How to ask LESS to ignore extend-purpose mixins in output

Tags: less

I was trying to adopt LESS 1.4 extend feature to my codebase, but found it would output all the `mixin`s.. For example:

```
.DefaultFont {
  font: 12px/1.5 sans-serif;
}
.NoPaddingMargin {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body:extend(.DefaultFont all, .NoPaddingMargin all) {

}
```

which generates

```
.DefaultFont,
body {
  font: 12px/1.5 sans-serif;
}
.NoPaddingMargin,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

But I don't want `.DefaultFont` and `.NoPaddingMargin` in the output.

I've tried to make `.DefaultFont` and `.NoPaddingMargin` as parametric mixins (`.DefaultFont() {}` and `body:extend(.DefaultFont() all) {}`) to avoid output, but seems the parser doesn't recognize it.

In Stylus there is `%` for this purpose. Is there any method to do the same in LESS? Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment LESS does not support what you want, its extend can be used only for selectors and not for parametric mixins (see https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1177).
So you either have to accept dummy .DefaultFont/.NoPaddingMargin selectors in the CSS output or fall back to a conservative mixin expansion instead of extend.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a class, you can reuse the class inside another ruleset:

```
.DefaultFont {
  font: 12px/1.5 sans-serif;
}
```

Used in another ruleset by calling it like so:

`.DefaultFont();`

If you want to prevent `.DefaultFont` from being compiled to a css ruleset itself, then add `()` to the end:

```
.DefaultFont() {
  font: 12px/1.5 sans-serif;
}
```

You still use it the same way, but this wont be compiled itself to a ruleset.

**Edit:**

http://lesscss.org/#-parametric-mixins

Declaring the mixin with the `()` will prevent it being compiled. A mixin that has no parameters or that has defaults does not require the usage of the mixin to require `()` only the declaration of the mixin.

> You can also use parametric mixins which don’t take parameters. This
>   is useful if you want to hide the ruleset from the CSS output, but
>   want to include its properties in other rulesets:

Comment: thx, but `body:extend(.DefaultFont() all) {}` failed to compile

Comment: I'm talking about declaring it, not the usage. Also I don't actually know where you get this `:extend` from since its not part of LESS documentation.

Comment: LESS is behind in documentation. The `extend()` feature was added in the beta testing of release 1.4, which gives a little documentation here: https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#140-beta-1--2.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `:extend` incorrectly, as the whole point of that feature is to *extend* the declaration of the original selector. If you simply want `body` to have the properties of the classes, you need to *include* them into it through a normal mixin:

```
body {
  .DefaultFont;
  .NoPaddingMargin;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a demonstration to the problem. Not looking for alternative solutions.